# $4$ chips are selected at random from a box of $30$ chips

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, problem-solving

> 4 chips are selected at random and without replacement from a box containing 5 black, 5 white, 5
>   red, 5 yellow, 5 blue and 5 green chips. Find the probabilities of the following events
>
> (a) Two of the chips are white, while the other two are of a second color
>
> (b) The selected chips are of three distinct colors.

I am having a lot of issues with problems like this. I don't know how I should think to solve them!

For $(a)$, I thought the following way:

There are $6$ colors to choose from for two balls, so we have $6\choose 1$ Having chosen a color, we need two balls from that color so there are $5\choose 2$ ways to pick $2$ balls of that color. Then there are $5$ colors to choose from for the second ball and third ball, so $5\choose 2$ ways of picking two colors of the remaining $5$ colors. Having picked two colors (other than white), there are $5\choose 1$ ways to pick one ball from one of those two colors, and $5\choose 1$ ways to pick one ball from the other of those two colors. And now I feel like I have answered question $(b)$ and not $(a)$.

I am extremely confused, and any help would be immensely appreciated!!

Comment: For (a), keep it simple: you're forced to pick $2$ chips from $5$ which must be white. Then you have $5$ other colors to choose from. Then once you choose that second color, you again need to choose $2$ chips from $5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 4 chips are selected at random and without replacement from a box containing 5 black, 5 white, 5 red, 5 yellow, 5 blue and 5 green chips.  Find the probability that two of the chips are white, and the other two are of a second color.

There are $\binom{30}{4}$ ways to select four of the thirty chips.

For the favorable cases, choose two of the five white chips, one of the other five colors, and two of the five chips of that color, which can be done in 
$$\binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{1}\binom{5}{2}$$
ways.

Hence, the probability that two of the four selected chips are white, and the other two are of a second color is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{5}{2}\dbinom{5}{1}\dbinom{5}{2}}{\dbinom{30}{4}}$$

> 4 chips are selected at random and without replacement from a box containing 5 black, 5 white, 5 red, 5 yellow, 5 blue and 5 green chips.  Find the probability that the selected chips are of three different colors.

Notice that this can only occur if we select two chips of one color and one chip each from two other colors.

Select the color from which two chips are drawn, select two chips of that color, select two colors from which one chip will be drawn (the colors must be different from the color from which two chips are drawn), and select one chip from each of those colors.

> This can be done in $$\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{1}^2$$ ways.

Divide by the number of ways of selecting four of the $30$ available chips to get the probability that the four chips are drawn from three different colors.

Comment: @scoopfaze and you both point to the same thing. So my questions is, we do not include $6\choose 1$ for $(a)$ beause we have already chosen the fact that it is white? So if instead, the question asked, $2$ of the same color, and $2$ of a different color, then my answer would be correct?

Comment: Yes, we do not need the factor of $\binom{6}{1}$ in part (a) since we have already chosen white.  The number of ways we could choose two chips each from two different colors is $$\binom{6}{2}\binom{5}{2}^2$$ since we must choose the two colors from which two chips each will be drawn and choose two of the five chips of each of those colors.

Comment: thank you very much!!!!